# How can we change the generator of an ideal, without changing the ideal itself?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I have following question:

> How can we change the generator of an ideal, without changing the ideal itself?

Now, I think that we can sort of simplify it and for example, take only the elements which are linearly independent. Kind of the same that we do with bases of vector spaces.
Would this be it? Could I add something? And, how would you apply this in practice; if you have an excercise giving you an ideal and asking to find a simpler generator of it(excercises that come very often in my course), what would your steps in doing this be?

I would be really happy to deepen my understanding of ideals so I thank you all in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

It's kinda hard to answer such a broad question, but if you want to express an ideal with different generators, then you may manually need to show that you're expressing the same ideal. For example say $I = \langle a, b, c \rangle$ in some ring $R$, but you want to expression this ideal as $\langle x, y\rangle$. Is this really the same ideal though? You can check by verifying that $I \subset \langle x, y\rangle$ and $\langle x, y\rangle \subset I$. Can you write $a,b$ and $c$ as a linear combination of $x$ and $y$ over $R$? Then can you write $x$ and $y$ as a linear combination of $a$, $b$ and $c$ over $R$?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it's a bit vague and don't expect a clean-cut answer like bases in linear algebra. You can't expect to change a set of generators into another set of generators in some methodical manner or expect to have that the minimal number of generators will be the same for any choice of generators.

e.g. You've seen this or will see this in module-theory but for example, over $\mathbb{Z}$, we have the equality of ideals $(2)=(6,10)$. The second choice of generators is minimal; you can't throw away either to obtain the same ideal.

Over nicer rings like $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{C}[x]$, you have tools like Euclid's algorithm at your disposal. General polynomial rings over multiple indeterminates is not easy; you have to introduce orderings on monomials, polynomial division doesn't work as nicely. You need a good choice of generators called Groebner basis to have things like a well-behaved polynomial division.

For more arbitrary nasty rings, there's just no hope for anything systematic. It will depend on the ring and the ideal.